# Netmiko catch exception with incorrect command

Tags: python-3.x, networking

[netmiko works with incorrect command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwUpY.png)
Hi Guys! How can I get exception with incorrect command. For now it does't raise exception

Comment: Explain would you have tried and what you expected from that

Answer (score 0):

Netmiko will send the commands that you specify down the SSH channel. You will need to look at the output of what comes back to see what happened.

In your above case, it should report you back as % invalid command from the remote device.

Netmiko doesn't sanity check the validity of your configuration commands, nor the response returned by the device.